# How add items to list

Tags: c#

I have class person,city and street. Number its House number. I was faced with such a problem that a person can live not only in 1 city, but for example in 2 (NY and LA). How add new city to person.

```
var live = new List<Live>();
    lives.Add(new Live
    {
        Person = new Person
        {
            FirstName = "Joe",
            LastName = "Doe"
        },
        City = new City
        {
            Name = "NY",
        },
        Number = 31
    });
```

Comment: Make City a list of Cities.

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is exactly. Can you [edit] to clarify?

Comment: try to learn how to create List<City> and update the question

Comment: @Pac0 Fair point, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you can change City to be Cities (a list of City) instead.

```
var live = new List<Live>();
lives.Add(new Live
{
    Person = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "Joe",
        LastName = "Doe"
    },
    Cities = new List<City>
    {
        new City 
        {
            Name = "NY",
        },
        new City
        {
            Name = "LA",
        }
    },
    Number = 31
});
```

In order to compile, your Person class should be defined like this :

```
public class Live
{
    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public List<City> Cities { get; set; }
    public int Number;
}
```

Also, as per your comment, if you want `Number` for each City, then the simplest solution I can imagine is to move Number from Person class to the City class.

Ultimately, it depends on what you need to model exactly, there are other ways.

Comment: I don't believe you can explicitly initialize a List like that, that ability is reserved for arrays.

Comment: no that list constructor works fine, any IEnumerable<City> works. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkbw11z0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: but how to add a `Number` to city? each city will have its own number. I have `public class Live
{
    public Person { get; set; }
    public City { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}`

Comment: @EvgeniyBojenov If the number is linked with a City, then it should be in the City class. If all this is from a Relational Database and / or for some reasons you don't want to add the Number property to the class City, then maybe you should do some kind of intermediate class (PersonCity) . Each PersonCity would contain a City and a related Number. And then, Person would contain a List<PersonCity>.

Comment: @Scornz as kenny said, this is perfectly valid initialization for any List, Array, Set, etc...

Comment: @EvgeniyBojenov On a more general comment : I can understand that you have doubts and struggle to create a correct model. That's a learning path for every coder. However, you have to realize that there are lots of different ways to achieve this, and some ways are better than other *for specific situations*. The more you clarify what you need to model exactly, what your program / teaching exercise is supposed to achieve, the better your question and the answers will be. (...)

Comment: (.. continued). Until now, all we could see in your question is : you want a Person to have several cities. Now you add the requirement that number is linked to the city. Maybe if you show what you need to have at the end exactly then we could help more precisely (also, this is an important point to learn programming : modelize precisely before coding !)

Comment: @EvgeniyBojenov Also, I edited my answer with a definition of the `Live` class that would work with my example.

Answer (score 0):

In the `Live` class, make the variable `City` a `City[]` instead, allowing someone to live in more than one city.

```
City City;
```

***TO***

```
City[] Cities;
```

And then you can change your code to look a bit like this...

```
var live = new List<Live>();
lives.Add(new Live
{
    Person = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "Joe",
        LastName = "Doe"
    },
    Cities = new City[]
    {
        new City {
            Name = "LA"
        },
        new City {
            Name = "NY"
        }
    },
    Number = 31
});
```

EDIT:

If you want `Cities` to be a `List<City>` then you can modify your code to look like this instead...

```
var live = new List<Live>();
lives.Add(new Live
{
    Person = new Person
    {
        FirstName = "Joe",
        LastName = "Doe"
    },
    Cities = new List<City>(
    new City[]
    {
        new City {
            Name = "LA"
        },
        new City {
            Name = "NY"
        }
    }),
    Number = 31
});
```